# MongoDB many-to-many search

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many

this is my collections: (many-to-many)

actors:

```
{
 _id: 1,
 name: "Name 1"
}
```

movies:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "The Terminator",
  production_year: 1984,
  actors: [
            {
              actors_id: 1,
              role_id : 1
            },
            {
             actors_id: 2,
             role_id : 1
            }
          ]
}
```

I can't get a list of actors for some movie

it is not a problem when I have this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "The Terminator",
  production_year: 1984,
  actors: [1,2,3,4,5] (actors id's)
}

var a = db.movies.findOne(name:"The Terminator").actors
db.actors.find({"_id":{$in:a}})
```

but, how can I make it with this above structure:

if, I do this `var a = db.movies.findOne(name:"The Terminator").actors`

it returns me this:

```
[
 {
  actors_id: 1,
  role_id : 1
 },
 {
  actors_id: 2,
  role_id : 1
 }
]
```

How do I get only this in array [1,2] (actors_id) to get the names of actors (with $in)

Thanks,
Zoran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. Within MongoDB you always query for documents so you have to make sure your schema is such that you can get all the information you need by querying for specific documents. There is no join/view like functionality in MongoDB.

Denormalization is usually the most appropriate choice in such cases. Your schema looks like it's designed for a traditional relational database and you will have to try and let go of some of the schema design principles that come with relational data.

Specifically for your example you could add the actor name to the embedded array so you have that information after querying for the movie.

Finally, consider if you're using the right tool for what you need to do. Too often people think of MongoDB is a "fast MySQL" which is entirely wrong. Document databases are very different to RDBMS and even k/v stores. If you have a lot of related data use an RDBMS.

Comment: I see that, thanks for your answer Remon. If I put name instead of an ID in the embedded array does that mean that if I want to update actor name I have to go through every movie and change it (instead of just changing it in a separate collection and referencing it via ID)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means. Note that you can do that update with one atomic write very easily over all movies but it might become a heavyweight operation in terms of execution time. This is why I said that you really have to consider if you're using the right tool. In this case the question you have to ask is "how often do actors change their name?". The answer is probably rarely, so you should be okay with having to run that update once every few days/weeks

Answer (score 0):

variable a in `db.movies.findOne(name:"The Terminator").actors` is an array of documents, so you'd have to make it an array of integers (ids)